# Jquery click function not working (displaying a hidden section)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a popup section that contains a form for someone to enter their email address when someone clicks on a link that says 'Mailing List.' The trouble is that when I click the link, the section doesn't appear. It works when I set it to hover but not click. I've run out of ideas on how to debug this. What am I missing?

HTML

```
<form class="mailing-list-input pull-right">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="mailing-list-input">
   <button class="mailing-list-btn">
     <img src="/assets/arrow.png" style="height: 12px; width: 12px; margin-right: 6px;">
   </button>
 </form>

 <footer class="footer footer-style">
   <section class="container pull-right">
     <ul class="list-inline btm-list">
       <li class="btm-menu-width">
         <a href="/" class="btm-menu-heading mailing-list">
             Mailing List
         </a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </section>
 </footer>
```

CSS for .mailing-list-input

```
.mailing-list-input {
 margin-right: 10rem;
 display: none;
 z-index: 98;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 5rem;
 right: 0;
}
```

Jquery File

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".mailing-list").click(function() {
   $(".mailing-list-input").css('display', 'block');
 },
 function() {
   $(".mailing-list-input").css('display', 'none')
 })
})
```

Comment: Here this might help you https://api.jquery.com/click/ there is only one handling function for click. You can just use toggle since that's what you are doing

Comment: `click()` only accepts one handler not two. Your thinking of `hover()`

Comment: You're not doing anything to prevent the link from actually being followed.

Comment: Here is a fiddle of your non working version: http://jsfiddle.net/j94suLjx/

Comment: You could use `console.log('display: '+$('.mailing-list-input').css('display'));` as last line in your onclick events for debugging. Also there're `$.hide()` and `$.show()` which you could use instead of changing css directly.

Comment: Oh and as it's an anchor tag you assign the clicks to - you might want to use `e.preventDefault()` to block default link navigation as well in your event handlers (`e` should be the first parameter of your event callback and basically contains information bout the event triggered

Answer (score 1):

The `click` function only accepts a single handler function. To achieve the behaviour you want, use a single handler and `toggle()` the element. Try this:

```
$(".mailing-list").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".mailing-list-input").toggle();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vvsua6ua/)

Note I also added `preventDefault()` to stop the default link behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what the OP appears to be trying to do this should be the Javascript:

```
$(".mailing-list").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(".mailing-list-input").css('display') === 'block') {
        $(".mailing-list-input").css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $(".mailing-list-input").css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

The click handler callback takes an argument that is the event object, you can call preventDefault on that object to stop the event from continuing through its lifecycle. Then if you want the link to toggle the element on every click you check to see if the element is visible or not and set its value accordingly.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j94suLjx/1/)